# Doubt in a simple inequality involving a integral

Tags: calculus

I am studying a old post in math stack and the author of the answer writes :

$$ \frac{2}{\pi} \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}  \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{sin \ t}{t + (k-1)\pi} \ dt < \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{sin \ t}{t  }  \ dt + \frac{4}{\pi^2} \displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k-1}$$

I am dont know how to obtain this, someone can give me a hint?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator of the integrand is larger than $(k-1)\pi$, and the sine is non-negative, so

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin t}{t+(k-1)\pi}\,dt < \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin t}{(k-1)\pi}\,dt = \frac{1}{(k-1)\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin t\,dt = \frac{2}{(k-1)\pi}$$

for $k \geqslant 2$.